# Determine covariance of X+Y vs X-Y

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, covariance

This challenge question was posed in class and I don't know the answer.
Can anyone explain?

[image]

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Note that you can settle the question of dependence without computing covariance.

Comment: well I could compute covariance Cov(X,Y) not sure what it means to compute that of the addition or subtraction of two vars?

Comment: @AlexanderMills $Cov(X+Y,X-Y)=Cov(X,X)+Cov(X,-Y)+Cov(Y,X)+Cov(-Y,Y)$. Can you go on?

Comment: I suggest:  start with dependence.  That's a good way to understand the variables. And it should not require heavy computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that X and Y are independent because they are the outcomes of two fair coins tossed independently. For each of them you can write:
$$
\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[Y] = 3.5
$$
$$
\text{Var}(X) = \text{Var}(Y) = \frac{35}{12}
$$
Then you can calculate Cov:
$$
\text{Cov}(X + Y, X - Y) = \text{Cov}(X, X) + \text{Cov}(X, -Y) + \text{Cov}(Y, X) + \text{Cov}(Y, -Y) 
$$
$$
= \text{Cov}(X, X) - \text{Cov}(Y, Y) = \text{Var}(X) - \text{Var}(Y) = 0
$$
So $X + Y$ and $X - Y$ have zero covariance. But note that they are not independent. For example consider the following events.
$$
X + Y = 12\quad,\quad X - Y = 1
$$
$$
\mathbb{P}[X - Y = 1] = \mathbb{P}[X = 2, Y = 1] + \mathbb{P}[X = 3, Y = 2] + \dots + \mathbb{P}[X = 6, Y = 5] > 0
$$
And Also:
$$
\mathbb{P}[X - Y = 1 | X + Y = 12] = 0
$$
So:
$$
\mathbb{P}[X - Y = 1 | X + Y = 12] \neq \mathbb{P}[X - Y = 1]
$$
Which means that $X + Y$ and $X - Y$ are dependent. You can conclude that if two random variables are independent their covariance equals zero but the other way doesn't always hold.